# activar .htaccess en debian/apache

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

tengo un problema con mi servidor apache que corre sobre debian 9.5 ya que no me detecta los .htaccess  ya active el Module rewrite  pero apache no reconoce estas redirecciones 
me pueden ayudar como se activa esto   esta de manera local corriendo en un virtual host en /var/www/mipagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando se crea el virtualhost  se debe de tener algo como esto

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin template.email
DocumentRoot template.docroot
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options Indexes
ServerName template.url

<Directory template.docroot>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
   AccessFileName .htaccess 

    </VirtualHost>
```

ya que sin el directorio con la ruta no me tomara los htaccess del proyecto